# problem with react-js-pagination css import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, pagination

I am using react js pagination https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination. but i got a problem with the CSS import.
I got the below error.
Module not found: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import "./App.css";
import GetCount from "./GetCount";
require("bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less");
```

which npm package need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

check LESS support in your application, if not follow this article https://medium.com/@giordano.cardillo/adding-sass-or-less-support-to-create-react-app-38cbe6c370ce

Try to use,

```
import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```